# is there a way to make second segment not to look for a function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Right now my website is set up to redirect to controller name home.

So basically when I type www.domain.com/home or www.domain.com I will end up in home controller.

Now in that controller // page I am loading some tables from database - that data will require pagination from time to time. which mean the link of the pagination is :
www.domain.com/home/3/

Now the way I have it set up when this address is being accessed CI goes to home controller and look for function name 3.

My question is:

is there a way to make it so CI will treat the 3 as a variable instead of a functions.
Also is there a way to do it just for that section of the website (I am asking this because I have my whole admin panel set up already with the normal "www.domain.com/admin/function/variable" )

Comment: ok found the solution thanks for anyone looking.

Comment: Never tell anyone what you found out...

Comment: i didnt thought many people doing codeignighter however what i did is  i went to application->configs->rounting.php and added a line:
$route['home/(:num)'] = "home";
which routs numbers that comes after home to home. seem to work.
you can see the full details at:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved the problem:

After reading some more i learned that i can route address to certain controllers/functions.

It appeared that at the config files(application/config/routes.php) there is a routing file and by adding a line or two to that file my problem was solved

I added the following line: $route['home/(:num)'] = "home"; which redirect home/number to home.

There are many ways of doing it however the above works fine for me.

For full explanation about routing at :

```
[ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/routing.html][1]
```

Hope that help other Codeigniters.

Answer (score 1):

I have the "first page" when I open the home controller, but if I want to see the next page the controller have a function for the pagination results. I.E.:

For my first page this is the link:

```
http://127.0.0.1/thesis/index.php/profiles/
```

When I change to the next page, the URL turns into:

```
http://127.0.0.1/thesis/index.php/profiles/list/20
```